# Can you lazy load a multiselect using Select2 or ui.multiselect.js?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, multi-select, jquery-select2

I have a need to allow multiple selections from a dropdown that has enough results I'll need to lazy load it. My test data involves 50,000 similarly-named values (i.e. value 1, value 2, value 3, ... value 40000, ... value 50000), which means if I use the standard "type a few letters and I'll load all the results" method I'll still get 50,000 results at once, and that isn't going to work.

I'm currently using two `select` plugins on my site:

`ui.multiselect.js` (from http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/) has a really slick interface for multiselects, but doesn't appear to support lazy loading

`select2` supports multiselects, and it supports lazy loading, but as far as I can tell it only supports lazy loading if the element it's replacing is an `<input type='hidden' />`. I tried turning a currently lazy loading hidden `<input>` into a `<select>`, and it failed to load any options. I also tried adding `multiple='multiple'` to a hidden `<input>`, and it did not affect the select2 at all.

Is there a way to make one of these plugins do both things at once?

Comment: What do you mean by lazy load? Do you mean lazy load the data via ajax or lazy render the results in the drop down after you have the full data set?

Comment: Did you really just ask if by "lazy load" I meant "lazy load" or something else? By "lazy load" I mean "lazy load."